# Configuration of dnsmasq which allows to append a domain `search` to /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: linux, networking, dns, resolve, dnsmasq

Lets's look at following `/etc/resolv.conf` at client side:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search reddog.microsoft.com 
nameserver 10.7.1.53
```

An `10.7.1.53` address is address of `dnsmasq` server. Is it possible to configure `dnsmasq` in such way that client of dnsmasq add some `search domain` ? I mean:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search reddog.microsoft.com my.domain.com
nameserver 10.7.1.53
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This sounds more like something the DHCP server should do, not dnsmasq.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, however if `dnsmasq` can act as DHCP as well?

Comment: https://www.linux.com/topic/networking/dns-and-dhcp-dnsmasq/

Comment: @Barmar Will it be sufficient to configure `dnsmasq` ?

Comment: I just gave you a link to a site that says how to configure the DHCP server in dnsmasq

Comment: I can see. However, I would rather get answer from someone who knows more about this subject.

Comment: well, that's not me. Post on [unix.se] like I said above